# How to use the chemfig tags to draw an esterification scheme (@tags in charge env)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

So for the love of me I cannot figure out chemfig. I tried for hours now to replicate a reaction mechanism and honestly regret not having just used photoshop. But here we are.

[image: What I am trying to replicate.]

I cannot find out how to put the correct tags at the positions of my charges to replicate this. Wherever I put it it just displays the tag I set as characters in the figure and not as tag. I then tried to just use the position at the bond I already have, but shifting the arrow origin also isn't an option. Can you please help me? This is my code so far

```
\setchemfig{scheme debug=false}
\schemestart
\chemfig[atom sep=2em]{
    H-[0]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
    -[0]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
    -[0]C
    (=[@{DB}1]\charge{[circle]0=\|, 90=\|}{O})
    -[7]O
    -[0]H
}
\+
\chemfig{
\charge{[circle]45:3pt=$+$}{H}
}
\arrow{<=>}
\schemestop
\chemmove[]{
\draw[shorten <=5pt,shorten >=2pt] (DB) .. controls +(2:3) and +(10:5) .. (DB);
%   \draw(dnl)..controls +(90:1cm)and+(north:1cm)..(atoc);
%   \draw[shorten >=6pt](db)..controls +(north:5mm)and+(100:1cm)..(atoh);
}
```

This gets me here:

[image: Result so far]

While we are at it: DO you know how to repair the bonds that go to the "charge Oxygen Atom"? For some reason the bond is extremely short especially in comparison to the others.

Answer (score 2):

you need to define the starting and ending points (@{...}) of the arrows

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\setchemfig{scheme debug=false}
\schemestart
\chemfig[atom sep=2em]{H-[0]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-[0]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-[0]C(=[@{DB}1]@{DB2}\charge{0=\|, 90=\|}{O})-[7]O-[0]H}
\+
\chemfig{@{DB3}\charge{45:3pt=+}{H}}
\arrow{<=>}
\chemfig[atom sep=2em]{H-[0]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-[0]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-[0]\charge{100:5pt=\ $\oplus $}{C}(-[1]\charge{90=\|, 150=\|}{O}-H)-[7]O-[0]H}
\schemestop
\chemmove[]{
    \draw[red, shorten <=2pt,shorten >=-1pt] (DB) .. controls +(150:10mm) and +(140:5mm) .. (DB2);
      \draw[red,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=2pt](DB2)..controls +(0:10mm)and+(90:15mm)..(DB3);
}

\end{document}
```

[image]